# Run .jar on server with php

Tags: java, php, jar

I made a .jar that edits a pagename.html file based on a .txt file located in the same folder.
Idea is that I (as webmaster) make changes to the .txt file and then, when someone visits my web page, a php code runs the .jar that edits the pagename.html, so when the user goes to pagename.html it will appear updated, based on what I wrote on the .txt file.
Is this possible? How?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [shell-exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: Why not write it directly in PHP? Why use Java at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute CLI commands with the `exec()` in php.

see: http://php.net/exec for more information.

To run your `jar` you can do something like: `exec('java -jar filename.jar', $response)`

The `$response` variable you can use to get any response the given command can give.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this.

- Use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) as @BrainStone suggested which will
  **return all of the output stream as a string**
- Use [exec](http://%3C?php%20exec(%22java%20-jar%20file.jar%20arguments%22,%20$output);%20?%3E) function which will **return the last line of the output.**

You may need to configure required permission depending on the server you are using and be careful with inputs you pass to the jar file because there is a security risk involved.